# how to pass ipv6 address in binary form to variable number of arguments in c

Tags: c

I have created a function which will receive variable number of arguments. In that variable number of arguments, one argument will come is ipv6 address which will come in the binary form and in my function I have to convert that ipv6 address into text format. how to receive and convert ipv6 address from binary to text in variable number of arguments

Comment: Please read [mcve] and provide one.